# How can i make unlimited Number of Labels in my vb prog with "Dim" Statement If i can -For example

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, label

How can i make unlimited Number of Labels in my vb prog  with "Dim" Statement If i can
-For example:

```
    for i = 0 to (unlimited number or integer Variable)
      dim label_i as label
    Next
```

label_i be a Different Label in every i loop
OR
    Dim sds As New List(Of Label)

```
    sds(1).Text = "Label1"
    sds(2).Text = "Label2"
    sds(3).Text = "Label3"
```

Or any other way or method
i am new in Programming and i need to make form has unlimited labels
.
.
Thank Advance

Comment: How do you want to add them? Button event ? Also do you want to have them formatted in line or?

Comment: yes in Button event and formatted 
I want to make new label with new properties(EX.name and text) and show it in form in a Different place in every loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an infinite while loop?

```
while (true)
   dim label_i as New label
end while
```

Comment: I want to make new label with new properties(EX.name and text) in every loop

Comment: So set those properties of label_i inside the loop.

Comment: i am sorry , i need these labels in Public statement to use it in the form and show it in a Different place in my form in every loop

Comment: just set the .Location, Name, .Text properties inside the loop. put the loop in a button click event and you are (never) done